# ejs get nested object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to pass the following json into an ejs template file.

```
    "image": {
       "0": {
           "url": "http://cdn.photos.ample_mls.com/az/20151113223546806109000000.jpg",
           "caption": "17596-20"
        },
    "totalCount": "39"
},
```

This is the ejs template. I am trying to list the all the url for images in the dictionary. Each image is a nested dictionary. How can I loop through them all and list out the url?

```
<ul>
 <% for(var i=0;i<image.length;i++){%>
   <%= image[i].url %>
 <%}%>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you **need to parse the json** using `JSON.parse()`. Then inside the template you can use **for-in loop** as follows

```
<% for (let key in image) { %>
   <% if (image.hasOwnProperty(key)) { %>
      <%= image[key].url %>
   <%}%>
<%}%>
```